# ajax mysql query acting weird

Tags: mysql, ajax

please go to lookaroundyou.net;
scroll to the bottom of the page and try to navigate videos through page numbers
u will notice that it is necessary to click twice in order to work.

please why is it acting like that?

thank you

Comment: you'll have a better success rate if you post the code here (of what you have) and ask for help rather then just redirecting someone to a site. Though you may have a linked broken page, with your reputation it looks too sketchy to just say "visit this link and browse around". (Maybe try to seclude the code in question and place it in a jsfiddle.net page if you'd like to show it working).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in the ajax.js file. you are executing the `check` function before the ajax call is made.

Change:

```
if (isFirefox() && firefoxVersion() >= 3) {
    httpReq.onload = check(div);
} else {
    httpReq.onreadystatechange = check(div);
}
```

to:

```
if (isFirefox() && firefoxVersion() >= 3) {
    httpReq.onload = function(){check(div);};
} else {
    httpReq.onreadystatechange = function(){check(div);};
}
```

Also, Please look into Sql Injection. At the very least you should not be passing the SQL queries in the url.

Comment: awesome man,you saved my day. many thanks. ;) sql injection ;) lame i, will fix it